# Getting "Failed to download repository information"  error while updating?

Tags: updates

I updated to 12.04 a week ago. Everything is fine, However when I recently tried to update by using the update manager, The update stopped and I received the error message:

`Failed to download repository information`

The following details were given:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Try to change your source list to main server and see to it if it download the files.

Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> Software Center -> Ubuntu Software -> Download From and change your server to Main. Reload your sources.

Comment: nice, this solves my issue (almost same), was getting stuff from Bosnia... half of Europe just for fun ^_^