# How to play MP3 files using Rhythmbox?

Tags: server, software-center, mp3

Yesterday I just installed the Ubuntu 12.04 for the first time, the problem is that I can't play and of the MP3 files that I have.

I get this error:

> Required plugin could not be found Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder

Please help me so I can play the files. Thanks

Comment: @bilal You can use VLC to play almost all kink of media files without installing any extra packages.

Comment: Python isn't missing, all the "codec missing" errors tell you that python requires codecs when the app in question uses python.

Answer (score 14):

First enable the Multiverse repository.to do that open `Software Sources` and click on `spftware restricted by copyright(multiverse repository)`(you can also enable all as i have done)

[image]

Then just open the terminal and type
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Also as in your case you do not seem to have `Python`. Install that by typing
`sudo apt-get install python`
if this does not work then download this package : [Python for 32 bit systems](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/82328510/python_2.7.2-7ubuntu2_all.deb)

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. But when I click on the 'Use this ource' to download it, it give me the following error "Failed to download repository information" and "Check your internet connection" whereas my computer IS connected to the internet. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: And this is the error that I get: "Required plugin could not be found

Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder"

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu comes with free and open source software by default, so proprietary software, like the software you need to play mp3's, is not included on a fresh install. But you can still install it. Click on the link below, or start the Ubuntu Software Center, from there, install a package called `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. That should solve your issue.

[image: Install via the software center]

Another way to get this done is just to try to play an mp3 file. A plugin search will appear. Click the `Install` button after the search is completed. This also works.

Comment: Also, you could just open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. But when I click on the 'Use this ource' to download it, it give me the following error "Failed to download repository information" and "Check your internet connection" whereas my computer IS connected to the internet. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: And this is the error that I get: "Required plugin could not be found

Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) decoder"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to change your download server. Python 2.7.3 is already pre-installed in ubuntu 12.04 so it is not python which causes the error but which throws it. And you also mentioned that you have a working internet connection but are nevertheless unable to download the ubuntu-restricted-extras.

[So take a look at this page to learn how to change your download server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132862/getting-failure-to-download-repository-information-error-while-updating)